# Transform out of position on drag

Tags: jquery, raphael

I'm using RaphaelJS and the FreeTransform-plugin. 
When i'm dragging an element, I want to do something but when I use the following code, the freetransform-handles our out of position:

```
var paper = Raphael('floor');

var el = paper.image('http://blog.knibbdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/NAlexander-Chair-Folding2.jpeg', 50, 50, 360, 360); 

var ft = paper.freeTransform(el);
var start = function () {
    this.ox = this.attr("x");
    this.oy = this.attr("y");
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
    console.log('Am i moving?');
},
up = function () {

};
el.drag(move, start, up);
```

If i remove 'el.drag()' the handles are on the correct position.
Fiddle-example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4x73N/6/

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: When dragging, I want to check if the element hits another element. Is the problem that I'm implementing 2 drag-functions on an element?? (el.drag AND freetransform-drag).

Comment: Yes it is. Investigate on FreeTransform plugin callbacks if there is any.

Comment: Well, i tried the drag-callback from the freeTransform-plugin but turned out it didn't callback every time... Currently I'm using mouseup/mousedown to work around this situation, but it's not ideal...

Comment: @rob1984 - Were you able to make it work?